# Widgets inside a Frame is not expanding to the full length placed inside another Frame in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Have a scenario where in I am trying to place two button inside a Frame and place that frame in another Frame in a  particular row. But the buttons placed inside the sub-frame is not expanding to the full length as shown in the snapshot below.

I tried with grid, place etc. but still didnt work. I haven't tried much on padding or filling etc. or setting some default size of the buttons.

[image]

Tried checking for some solution they kept saying you need to rowconfigure and columnconfigure the root widget etc. but even that didnt work. Any suggestion how to make sure the widgets expand to full length ?

Below is the code I tried: For frame and the buttons.

```
#!/usr/intel/bin/python2.7

import Tkinter
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import * 
import ttk
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import subprocess
import shlex
import os 
#from PIL import Image, ImageTk
#import Image, ImageTk
import time
import string
import tkFont
import ttk

class MyApp:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.rel3 = None
        self.ib_frame = None
        self.rb =  None
        self.eb = None

        if not (self.rel3):
            self.rel3 = Label(root, font=MyFontH2, text="What Type Of Widget You Wanted To Create: ")
            self.rel3.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky='W', padx=38)
            self.rel3.rowconfigure(6,weight=1)
        else:
            self.rel3.grid()

        # Frame Code
        if not (self.ib_frame):   
            self.ib_frame = Frame(root)
            self.ib_frame.grid(row=7, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky='WE')
            self.ib_frame.rowconfigure(7,weight=1)
            #self.ib_frame.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        # Button1 Code
        if not self.rb: 
            self.rb = Button(self.ib_frame, background="royalblue1", activebackground="blue2", text="RTMM")    
            self.rb.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='WE')
            self.rb.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
            # self.rb.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)

        # Button2 Code
        if not (self.eb):     
            self.eb = Button(self.ib_frame, background="orangered", activebackground="orangered3", text="ECG")
            self.eb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='WE')
            self.eb.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
            #self.eb.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH) 

root = Tk()
root.title("Test UI")

MyFontH2 = tkFont.Font(family='courier', size=20, weight=tkFont.BOLD)

myapp = MyApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Example output: Wondering by the two buttons added sits in the right corner when I added them in a separate frame and then placed it in row in the root frame.

[image]

**NEW UPDATE: I tried the below code but still the problem is same. Am i doing something wrong ?**

```
#!/usr/intel/bin/python2.7

import Tkinter
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import * 
import ttk
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import subprocess
import shlex
import os 
#from PIL import Image, ImageTk
#import Image, ImageTk
import time
import string
import tkFont
import ttk

class MyApp:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.rel3 = None
        self.ib_frame = None
        self.rb =  None
        self.eb = None
        self.fb = None
        self.l_1 = None
        self.e_1 = None


        if not (self.l_1):
            self.l_1 = Label(text="Choose the Config: ")
            self.l_1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='W')
            self.l_1.rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
            self.l_1.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        else:
            self.l_1.grid_forget(); self.l_1 = None
            self.l_1 = Label(text="Choose the Config: ")
            self.l_1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='W')
            self.l_1.rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
            self.l_1.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        if not (self.e_1):    
            self.e_1 = Entry(bg="goldenrod")
            self.e_1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='WE')
            self.e_1.rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
            self.e_1.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
        else:
            self.e_1.grid_forget(); self.e_1 = None
            self.e_1 = Entry()
            self.e_1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='WE')
            self.e_1.rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
            self.e_1.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)


        # Frame Code
        if not (self.ib_frame):   
            self.ib_frame = Frame(root)
            self.ib_frame.grid(row=7, column=0, columnspan=**2**, sticky='WE')
            #self.ib_frame.rowconfigure(7,weight=1)
            self.ib_frame.columnconfigure((0,1,2),weight=1)

        # Button1 Code
        if not self.rb: 
            self.rb = Button(self.ib_frame, background="royalblue1", activebackground="blue2", text="VEGI")    
            self.rb.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='WE')
            #self.rb.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self.rb.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
            # self.rb.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)

        # Button2 Code
        if not (self.eb):     
            self.eb = Button(self.ib_frame, background="orangered", activebackground="orangered3", text="DESERT")
            self.eb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='WE')
            #self.eb.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self.eb.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
            #self.eb.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH)

        # Button2 Code
        if not (self.fb):     
            self.fb = Button(self.ib_frame, background="tan1", activebackground="tan4", text="FRUIT")
            self.fb.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='WE')
            #self.fb.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
            self.fb.columnconfigure(2,weight=1)
            #self.fb.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH)     

root = Tk()
root.title("Test UI")

MyFontH2 = tkFont.Font(family='courier', size=20, weight=tkFont.BOLD)

myapp = MyApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

UPDATE : Got it fixed. Its the columnspan.

Comment: _I tried with grid, place etc. but still didnt work_. What code did you try with? What do you mean by didn't work?

Comment: From the looks of it, your `Frame` didn't expand instead of the buttons. You need to show how you manage your frame.

Comment: If the buttons don't _appear_ to be expanding, it's probably because the frame they are in isn't expanding. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, my bad.. Forgot to past the code. Have added an example of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can expand the columns in the frame `ib_frame` with `columnconfigure`:

```
# Frame Code
if not (self.ib_frame):   
    self.ib_frame = Frame(root, bg='tan')
    self.ib_frame.grid(row=7, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky='WE')
    self.ib_frame.rowconfigure(7, weight=1)
    self.ib_frame.columnconfigure([0,1], weight=1)
    #                               ^
    #                      expand both columns
```

Comment: I tried your updates recently but the issue still persists.. Am i doing anything wrong ? I tried adding up the columnconfigure for the frame, but still the buttons in the frame are side tracked in the column 0 but expected them to be expanded.